# Finding the version details of the Jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, automation

I have list of Jars in the local directory and My objective is to make the utility that fetches the details (version nad name) of the Jars and populate them in POM.xml file automatically . 
I am not able to find the version of the JArs with the help of Java utility program. Kindly guide me if nay pointers.
Regards,Puneet Verma

Comment: First i would take a look into the MANIFEST.MF file of the appropriate jar's might help but not always...

Answer (score 0):

You can use decompiler or you can rename your .jar to .zip and in meta-inf directory you would find manifest file, in that you can find the version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no surefire way to do this - the [manifest file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) would be your best bet but the [Package Version Information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html) is optional, so there's no guarantee it would be present (and certainly isn't there by default).

That aside, you seem to be confusing what the dependencies in a Maven POM are for.  You don't start with local jars and build a POM; you declare the dependencies (which requires not only a version but also group id and name) and Maven will retrieve them from a public repository, adding them to a local repository as part of the build.

Comment: Thanks for the information . If manifest file wont be there in all the cases . Can u suggest what other options can i opt ?

Comment: There aren't other options, version is a Maven concept not a Java one